# How to purge / prevent using the prometheus local storage when using remote_write

Tags: prometheus

I configured Prometheus to push metrics using `remote_write` but the local storage is still in use and keeps growing

How could Prometheus be configured to stop storing locally and only push metrics or to minimize the retention policy from the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus can run in agent mode. In this mode it doesn't store data locally - it just sends the scraped samples to the configured remote storage systems. See [this article](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/11/16/agent/) for details.

P.S. see also the project I work on -  [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) - this is lightweight  Prometheus-compatible agent, which understands Prometheus scrape configs. It usually requires lower amounts of memory and CPU comparing to Prometheus when scraping the same targets.